# What are the secret acheivements and how to track them?

Tags: hearthstone

I've got a couple of little bonuses of gold at some random occasions when I got things like 100 victories or so.

Thing is, it's written nowhere what are those acheivements are and at how much % they are completed.

Is there any way to know what are those "acheivements" are and track the completion of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no place in game where the achievements are listed. However here is a list:

Arrrrrr!!!

- Requirement: Acquire every Pirate.
- Bloodsail Corsair, Bloodsail Raider, Captain Greenskin, Dread Corsair, Southsea Captain, Southsea Deckhand
- Reward: Captain's Parrot

Beta Hero!

- Requirement: Thank you for helping to test our store!
- Make a store purchase during the beta.
- Reward: Gelbin Mekkatorque (golden)

Big Winner

- Requirement: Win 1,000 games in any mode.
- Reward: 300 gold

Chicken Dinner

- Requirement: Win 100 games in any mode.
- Reward: 300 gold

Crafting Time

- Requirement: Disenchant a card.
- Reward: 95 Arcane Dust

Crushed Them All!

- Requirement: Defeat every Expert AI Hero.
- Reward: 100 gold

Enter The Arena

- Requirement: Enter The Arena.
- Reward: 1 free arena play

First Blood

- Requirement: Complete a game in Play mode.
- Reward: 1 Card Pack

Golden Arrrrrr!!!

- Requirement: Acquire every Golden Pirate.
- Reward: Captain's Parrot (golden)

Golden Mrglglglgl!

- Requirement: Acquire every Golden Murloc.
- Bluegill Warrior, Coldlight Oracle, Coldlight Seer, Grimscale Oracle, Murloc Raider, Murloc Tidecaller, Murloc Tidehunter, Murloc Warleader
- Reward: Old Murk-Eye (golden)

Got the Basics!

- Requirement: Collect every card in the Basic Set.
- Reward: 100 gold

Level Up

- Requirement: Get any class to level 10.
- Reward: 1 Card Pack

Mrglglglgl!

- Requirement: Acquire every Murloc.
- Reward: Old Murk-Eye

One of Everything!

- Requirement: Collect every card in the Expert Set.
- Reward: 100 gold

Ready to Go!

- Requirement: Unlock every Hero.
- Reward: 100 gold

Ready to Rock!

- Requirement: Thank you for attending BlizzCon 2013!
- Reward: Elite Tauren Chieftain (golden)

iPack

- Requirement: Awarded for playing a game on the iPad.
- Reward: 100 gold

[Source](http://hearthstone.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements)